# Why images are blur using React Native <Image/>?

Tags: css, image, react-native, blur

my image once fitted to the screen is blurry, even though it is actually in high quality, what can I do to adapt it to the width of the smartphone without losing quality?

```
<View key={item[0]} style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',}}>
                        <Image style={{
                                width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                                height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
                                resizeMode: "contain",
                                alignSelf: "center",
                            }} source={{uri: item[0]}} />
                    </View>
```

Comment: May be you can try to only give width or height because anyway you use "contain" to see if it changes or not. The images are stretched or just bad quality ?

Comment: the image is not of low quality, because when I open it in the browser and zoom it is perfect. And if I just give a value, the image disappears